# How to copy and rename a file with CopyWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, file-copying

As part of a build process I already use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy some files from the source to the built directory.
Whilst copying I would also like to change some file names.
For example from `test.tsx.snap` to `test.js.snap`.
It looks like this should be possible from the docs as they have [path parameters for the templates](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#template) but it's not clear.
I'd like to do this for a directory of files so globing is also required.

Currently this does not work:

```
const config = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, './test/snapshots/[name].tsx.[ext]'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, './test/snapshots/[name].js.[ext]')
      }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you're going to close vote the please point me to the appropriate stackexchange site.  Please also bear in mind that this is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" so falls within stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`test` option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#test) to capture RegEx groups, which you then can use in your `to`.

```
[
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, './test/snapshots/*.tsx.*'),
      to: '[2].js.[ext]',
      test: /(.+\/)?(.+)\.tsx\.snap/
    }
  ], options)
]
```

Comment: This option does not seem to be documented on the latest version of the package though : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#patterns

Comment: it was replaced by `transformPath`, which itself was then replaced in favor of the Function type of the `to` option https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit late to this, but I think probably an easier solution is to use the toType option to specify that the 'to' option is a template

```html
const config = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, './test/snapshots'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, './test/snapshots/[name].js.[ext]'),
        toType: 'template',
      }
    ])
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// webpack.config.js

```js
{
  plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: './sample/dir',
          to: ({ absoluteFilename }) => {
            // FILENAME_REGEX is a regex that matches the file you are looking for...
            const { fileName } = absoluteFilename.match({ FILENAME_REGEX });
            return `destination/dir/changeFileName(fileName).yaml`
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]
}
```